# One of my suggested edits has been rejected, but by reviewing it I notice my post isn't compared to the original one

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I have suggested an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8011709) that was "rejected and edited" by a moderator because it doesn't correct critical issues. Well, I have to say that, by looking at it, I totally agree: the edits are trivial. **But that is not what I edited!**

The original post, which you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30152389/revisions), contained two 3x3 matrices that were formatted as normal text, which Markdown displays on one line, thus making them difficult to understand. Therefore I tried to edit them by adding the four spaces at the beginning, and while I was at it I also fixed other minor things.

Now if you check my edit again you'll see that my version does contain the proper formatting for the matrices, but somehow this is not reported as a difference with the original post. From there, it looks like Alpha's post was already properly formatted - but if you check the history again, no it wasn't, and the one who fixed the formatting was yet another user, BLUEPIXY, who is not shown in my edit. This looks strange.

So I have 2 possible explanations:

1. Both BLUEPIXY and I tried to fix Alpha's question, but he has more than 2000 rep so he skipped the review queue, and his change was accepted before I submitted my change. Then my edit looks an edit of Alpha's original post, but it is silently being compared to BLUEPIXY's changes. If this is the case, I'd say what happened is that the author of the post I tried to edit (Alpha) was recorded when I clicked on "Edit", but his post was replaced by the one (BLUEPIXY's) that was present when I clicked on "Save edits".
2. Maybe Alpha himself changed his post during the 5-minutes grace period, which doesn't leave a trace in the history. This would explain why my edit looks like it was applied to a corrected version of his post. But on the other hand this wouldn't explain why the history reports BLUEPIXY's change.

So I don't think 2) is correct. I think the right one is 1). But in any case it looks like there are some inconsistencies. Is this a bug due to a critical race between edits? Or am I missing something?

Whatever the reason, I think a simple way to prevent this would be to notify the author of a suggested edit that in the meanwhile the original post has been updated, and offer him to reload it. Then he could check whether his proposed change still makes sense.

Comment: It could also be that BLUEPIXY submitted his edit between you clicking to begin editing and clicking to submit your edit.

Comment: @nhgrif: actually it's what I meant with point 1.